# Attribute Routing with BaseClass implementation: Correcltly listed but still fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've set attribute routing on a controller class which inherits a base class where I handle I18N culture set/selection logic (as described in article [ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)) but that process fails, although route seemed to be set correctly.

```
[RoutePrefix("{culture}")]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Route("Hakkimda")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

[image: Glimpse Routing Debug Screen]

When I try to get to link I see grey screen of death on browser with this on address bar:

```
http://localhost:53530/tr-tr/Hakkimda?MS_DirectRouteMatches=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BSystem.Web.Routing.RouteData%5D
```

I believe the problem is the way base controller implements I18N logic which is based on BeginExecuteCore overloading.

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    string cultureName = RouteData.Values["culture"] as string; 

    // Attempt to read the culture cookie from Request
    if (cultureName == null)               
        cultureName = Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0 ? Request.UserLanguages[0] : null; // obtain it from HTTP header AcceptLanguages

    // Validate culture name
    cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // This is safe


    if (RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName) {

        // Force a valid culture in the URL
        RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant(); // lower case too

        // Redirect user
        Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);                
    }


    // Modify current thread's cultures            
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;


    return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
}
```

Probably execution precedence of BeginExecuteCore and routing have some mismatch but my knowledge on both don't suffice to solve it.

I've seen this article([What’s New in ASP.NET MVC 5.2 : Attribute routing improvements](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-mvc-52#attributerouting)) but example provided there was a bit different and because it's new there aren't other examples on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mr-anton's answer will stop you getting rubbish in the address bar but It'll also stop the language changing.

I had this issue after a change from MVC5 to MVC5.2
[This answer says it is a Microsoft issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080707/requestcontext-routedata-does-not-contain-action)

The workaround is to see if the route data is in a nested route key

```
        var routeData = RouteData;
        if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("MS_DirectRouteMatches"))
        {
            routeData = ((IEnumerable<System.Web.Routing.RouteData>)routeData.Values["MS_DirectRouteMatches"]).First();
        }
        string cultureName = routeData.Values["culture"] as string;
```

And then it just works.

Comment: Can't test it now, but looks like a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

remove this code

```
  if (RouteData.Values["culture"] as string != cultureName) {

    // Force a valid culture in the URL
    RouteData.Values["culture"] = cultureName.ToLowerInvariant(); // lower case too

    // Redirect user
    Response.RedirectToRoute(RouteData.Values);                
}
```

Comment: would you bother explaining why?